# error in ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to implement ajax when the button is clicked, but the ajax is not wroking, can anyone tell me what's wrong, many thanks! what I want is that when click the "Move marked to set" button, in the "formstatus" div should display some message I defined in the addtoset.php, but currently it direct to to "#"page instead of remain on the same page

here is my ajax code

```
    $('#movetoset').click(function() {
   var fail="";
   var hint="";
              if ($('#selectsett').val() === 'General') {

         fail += "Please chooose a set.\n";
    }

  for(j=0;j< array_str_idnum.length;j++)
  {



              if( document.getElementById('check' + array_str_idnum[j]).checked ==false){
                  hint='1';

              }


  }
        if(hint=="1"){
                  fail += "Please check all the box.\n";
              }

      if(fail == ""){

           var str = $("#complicated").serialize();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "addtoset.php",
               data: str,
                               cache: false,
               success: function(msg)
               {
                    $("#formstatus").ajaxComplete(function(){


                                               $(this).fadeIn("slow").html(msg)

                    });
                }

             });

          return true;
      }else{
          alert(fail);
          return false;
      }


     });
```

here is my html code

```
    <form id ="complicated" method = 'post' action = '#'>


    <div class="fancybuttonwrapper" style="margin-left:480px;"><span class="button"><span>
       <input type="submit" class="form_button" id="movetoset" value="  Move Marked to  Set"></span></span> </div>




       <select name="sets" id ="selectsett">
        <option value="General">Select Set</option>
        <option value="Ceremony">Ceremony</option>
        <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
        <option value="Garden">Garden</option>
        <option value="Longname">This is max length</option>
      </select>
      </div>

   <div id="formstatus"></div>

  </form>
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that it's not working? Describe in detail if you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your array `array_str_idnum` is not defined.
Further, you have to return false, else your form gets posted and so no ajax call at all.

Try this script. (always return false when you are in a form, else it gets send)

```
$('#movetoset').click(function() {
    console.log("here")
    var fail = "";
    var hint = "";
    if ($('#selectsett').val() === 'General') {

        fail += "Please chooose a set.\n";
    }
        var str = $("#complicated").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addtoset.php",
            data: str,
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#formstatus").ajaxComplete(function() {


                    $(this).fadeIn("slow").html(msg)

                });
            }

        });

        return false;
 });
```

check out: http://jsfiddle.net/wRNQv/5/ there is a running version.

Comment: hi I defined that assay just didn't include it here, I need that loop to check which box is checked, so shouldn't be a problem I think, thanks

Comment: please check again. Corrected some stuff. You need to return false, else your form is posted.

Comment: if you return true to a "submit" input field, it gets posted and your ajax call is aborted.

Comment: Hi! I posted an ajax script that also displays messages (and an image) by calling some php script. Unfortunately is not jquery, its XmlHttp, however it works fine and is asynchronous, and might be of some help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407292/optimize-php-script-to-prevent-max-execution-time-limit/7408116#7408116

Answer (score 0):

Add fail handler to Ajax call and see what you get as error

```
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){       

       }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you do not prevent the default action from executing. So the request may be started, but the page immediately redirects to different URL (defined in form's `action`).

Change the following part of the code:

```
$('#movetoset').click(function() {
    var fail="";
```

into the following:

```
$('#movetoset').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting
    var fail="";
```

It should help. Please let me know if it did.

Comment: @tony: You said `...but currently it direct to to "#"page...` - is the page still redirected, when you click on the button with ID of `movetoset`?

Comment: no, it's not, but give me nothing, the formstauts div doesn't show any message I defined in the php file

Comment: @tony: ok, so first of all the "doesn't work" doesn't say anything to us - my solution fixed one part and without it the script would not work anyway. Now you need to solve the other part of the problem. As evildead mentioned in the comment to his/her answer.